# Connecting to different tcp-port on VmWare

Tags: apache, virtualization, virtualhost

I am web-programmer. I work on WIndows 7, but I host my projects on Debian 6 Squeeze, installed on VmWare Workstation and configured with NAT so,that I can access web-server from windows by IP '192.168.195.222'. But I want absolute url from Windows to each project on virtual machine (debian). For this, I set up every project on different port.
So I input this code to /etc/apache2/httpd.conf on my VM:
    
DocumentRoot /home/poject1

Listen 127.0.0.1:8080

So now I want to access my project from Windows like 'http://192.168.195.222:8080', but browser does not find anything by this url. But from debian I can access this project by url 127.0.0.1:8080
How can I access this project from Windows?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

`Listen 127.00.1:8080` means that your virtual server will only be accepting connections from itself.

Use `Listen 8080` to listen on all network interfaces instead.